# How to return customise response using django rest api

Tags: django-rest-framework

Like nested dict of list ?Can we use serializers to return customise or we need to write django view to customize the output of data ?

**models.py**

```
 class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email       = models.EmailField()

class Article(models.Model):
    headline    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date    = models.DateField()
    reporter    = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**view.py**

```
class ReporterView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset            =   Reporter.objects.all()
    serializer_class    =   ReportSerializer


class ArticleView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset            =   Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class    =   ArticleSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('reporter/',ReporterView.as_view(),name='reporter'),
  path('artical/',ArticleView.as_view(),name='article'),
]
```

These apis return data as follow :
 for api **reporter/**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Nero",
        "last_name": "Sutton",
        "email": "dugunox@mailinator.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Maia",
        "last_name": "Stark",
        "email": "kacepub@mailinator.com"
    }
]
```

**for api 'artical/'**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "headline": "Consequatur",
    "pub_date": "2020-02-14",
    "reporter": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Nero",
        "last_name": "Sutton",
        "email": "dugunox@mailinator.com"
    }
},
```

**Now i want to create new api which can return data in following format:**

```
[
{    "first_name": "Nero",
     "email": "dugunox@mailinator.com"
     "reportinf_artical":[
             { "headline": "Consequatur1", "pub_date": "2020-02-14",},
             { "headline": "Consequatur2", "pub_date": "2020-02-14",},
             { "headline": "Consequatur3", "pub_date": "2020-02-14",},
         ]
  },
  {    "first_name": "Nero",
     "email": "dugunox@mailinator.com"
     "reportinf_artical":[
             { "headline": "Consequatur1", "pub_date": "2020-02-14",},
             { "headline": "Consequatur2", "pub_date": "2020-02-14",},
             { "headline": "Consequatur3", "pub_date": "2020-02-14",},
         ]
  },
  #and so on....
]
```

Comment: Could you share your Models or provide more information of what it is that you want to serialize/deserialize?

Comment: Will you please clarify your question by adding the models you used here?

Comment: @Sasja Vandendriessche Hope,this can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one model field called **ListField** from the **django_mysql.models** module that may be applicable for this.

```
from django.db.models import Model, CharField
from django_mysql.models import ListCharField

class MyPurchase(Model):
    category = CharField(max_length=20)
    purchase_date = DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = ListCharField(
        base_field = CharField(max_length=100)
    )
```

It may look something of this sort. You can set the number of items you can add to **products**. Have a look at its docs if you want to read further  into it.

https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: but data was retriving from multiple models

Comment: @Prashant then you should edit your question and add those model's. It is impossible for the community to enumerate every possible way to get to the output you expect.